# Using generics and polymorphism, getting error

Tags: c#, .net, generics, polymorphism

For one week I'm getting the below type missmatch error. I search through the internet, looked at how to use generics, but I couldn't find what I'm doing wrong. could anyone please tell me how to fix this problem

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    JSonHttpClient httpClient;
    // ....

    public ListAlertsResponse ListAlerts(ListAlertsRequest listAlertsRequest) {
         //HERE COUSES THE ERROR !!!
         return (ListAlertsResponse)httpClient.DoGetRequest(listAlertsRequest);
    }
}
```

error:

```
Error   5   Argument 1: 
     cannot convert from 'ListAlertsRequest' to BaseRequest<BaseResponse>'
```

My classes and interfaces

```
public class JsonHttpClient {
    public BaseResponse DoGetRequest(BaseRequest<BaseResponse> request) {
        return new BaseResponse(...) }
}

public interface Request {}
public interface Response {}
public abstract class BaseResponse : Response {}
public abstract class BaseRequest<T> : Request where T : BaseResponse {}
public class ListAlertsResponse : BaseResponse {}
public class ListAlertsRequest : BaseRequest<ListAlertsResponse> {}
```

Comment: Looks pretty simple, method DoGetRequest simply can not accept type of ListAlertsRequest, instead it accepts BaseRequest<BaseResponse>

Comment: let me be more cleare please, I will edit the question

Comment: you need to make your generic class co-variant.

Comment: show me the code on the DoGetRequest()..... what objects are you creating?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

listAlertsRequest is not a subclass of BaseRequest

```
public class JsonHttpClient
{
    public BaseResponse DoGetRequest<T>(BaseRequest<T> request) where T : BaseResponse
    {
        return new BaseResponse(...)
    }
}
```

Comment: possibly the error comes from that but I'm extending it right?

Comment: in fact you don't need the ListAlertsRequest, your BaseRequest<T> makes it irrelevant.

Comment: now I'm getting this error Error 1 The type 'T' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'BaseRequest<T>'. There is no boxing conversion or type parameter conversion from 'T' to BaseResponse'.

Comment: @TMcKeown: `where T : BaseResponse`

Answer (score 4):

You're sending a type `ListAlertsRequest` to `DoGetRequest` which needs a parameter of type `BaseRequest<BaseResponse>`. `ListAlertsRequest` is not of type `BaseRequest<BaseResponse>`

Answer (score 2):

DoGetReq returns BaseResponse:
 public BaseResponse DoGetRequest(BaseRequest request)

so either return the actual type you're hoping for (ListAlertsResponse), or write a routine to convert it, or (best imo), have ListAlertsResponse take BaseResponse in its constructor and grab whatever info is needed at that point.

Comment: The error is the other way around... It can not convert to pass the params

Answer (score 2):

A little improvement of T McKeown's answer:

```
    public TResponse DoGetRequest<TResponse>(BaseRequest<TResponse> request) 
        where TResponse : BaseResponse
    { 
        return default(TResponse); 
    }
```

Since BaseRequest is constrained by parameter `T`, you should put constraint on generic method too. Also, you can omit casting from caller code, using generic return type:

```
// response is already ListAlertsResponse
var response = httpClient.DoGetRequest(listAlertsRequest);
```

Answer (score 2):

`DoGetRequest` returns *BaseResponse* which you can't cast to a type of a derived class `ListAlertsResponse`.  Think about the following, what if:

```
public class BaseResponse
{
    public int NumberA { get; set; }
}
```

And the derived class had

```
public class ListAlertsResponse : BaseResponse
{
    public string StringB { get; set; }
}
```

What do you think this cast will set `test.StringB` to?

```
var test = (ListAlertsResponse)httpClient.DoGetRequest(listAlertsRequest);
```

The runtime doesn't know how to properly cast this for you, if you want to do this, you need to create a converter yourself, or better yet, not do this, you can cast into a base class, but not the other way around.